# How to get the queue size of the executor in real time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous

Supposed i have this `application.java`

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(50);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(5000);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("sm-async-");
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

My goal is to create an alert if the current real time queue size of the async executor is in 80% or nearly the limit. I think we can get the value from `executor.getThreadPoolExecutor().getQueue().size();`. Im currently stuck on how to achieve that

Comment: `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor ` is coming from springboot?

Comment: Autowire the `Executor`, cast to `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and then use the snippet in your question?

Comment: yes sir. It is coming from spring boot

Comment: @Kayaman thank you for a possible solution, im thinking that too. But just asking whether there is different approach to reach the objective

Comment: @Kayaman there's nothing wrong. Just want to know the other way of solving that i cant think of :). Sorry if its offend you

Comment: @zd14 I'm not offended. It's just that there can be dozens of ways to solve things, and if you don't want the simplest way, there should be a good reason. We can't write 20 answers describing all the possible ways you could do this, because it wouldn't be useful.

Comment: alright @Kayaman , roger that

Comment: @zd14 seems your root goal is monitoring the queue and sending an alert, but I wouldn't do that programmatically at all. It's not really the program's responsibility, it would be the responsibility of the tool that monitors the program, or the developers to make sure that there is enough processing power. Basically you have the wrong goal. Don't mix monitoring logic with business logic. What happens when the threshold crosses 80%? Do you try to throttle requests, or what?

Comment: @Kayaman yeah, you are right. Maybe i asked the question poorly. If it does cross 80%, an alert will be sent for example to slack channel so others would know. It just for monitoring, as of now i dont intend to block or throttle the request

Comment: @zd14 then you can get away with polling it every N seconds. Making it event based would be a lot more complex, and obviously you wouldn't even need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Controller
public class QueueMonitorController {

    @Autowired
    private Executor executor;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/queuesize", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public int queueSize() {
        ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = (ThreadPoolExecutor)executor;
        return tpe.getQueue().size();
    }
}
```

If you can provide the bean as a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, then you don't even need the cast. The internal implementation of `size()` in `LinkedBlockingQueue` (which ThreadPoolExecutor uses) is `AtomicInteger.get()`.

So there's no need to get creative and build your own mechanisms, it's all built-in. Based on Spring 4.2, but shouldn't depend on the version too much.

---

So the root goal is to monitor the queue, and send an alert when queue is 80% full. This should not go into your code which is responsible for making sure that your business logic works. You shouldn't make hacks there to account for lack of resources. If the idea is that you should throttle users when the queue is packed, there are far better ways to handle those.

Since the idea is to do "light monitoring", i.e. there's no attempt to **handle** a case when queue is 80% full, a polling solution would be lightweight enough. Considering that the executor can be easily injected to a separate `Controller`, it won't even mess up your "real" code.

Comment: it should be "return tpe.getQueue().size();"

Answer (score 2):

As `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` does not expose any API you can get the queue used by it. However, you are free to extend  `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`  and create a `CustomThreadPoolTaskExecutor` override the `createQueue`.

```
public class CustomThreadPoolTaskExecutor extends ThreadPoolTaskExecutor{

    private BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue;

    @Override
    protected BlockingQueue<Runnable> createQueue(int queueCapacity) {
        queue = super.createQueue(queueCapacity);
        return queue;
    }

    public BlockingQueue<Runnable> getQueue(){
      return queue;
    }
}
```

Now you can create `asyncExecutor` like below :

```
@Bean
public Executor asyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new CustomThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    //set other properties
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

Your `CustomThreadPoolTaskExecutor` executor has public method `getQueue` and you can use that to get the queue.

Comment: Exactly the solution I thought of. The only thing is, I believe that actively polling `queue.getSize()` may worsen performance or produce false results. I suppose it is better to wrap `BlockingQueue` with a class that will feature `AtomicInteger` that will be incremented/decremented every time a new task is added/deleted. That way the event of queue being filled over 80% will be produced just in time.

Comment: @Xobotun the queues do that internally, `LinkedBlockingQueue.size()` is `count.get()`, where `count` is an `AtomicInteger`. It's just that `BlockingQueue` interface doesn't offer a `size()`, so you need to cast to the implementing class.

Comment: @Kayaman, oh, I did not know that, thanks. But main idea was to create wrapper to produce an event after a 800th task added, just in case OP will have more frequent submits to the executor than cron-style polling if he chooses to do so. :D

Comment: @Xobotun but adding 800 tasks doesn't mean the queue is 80% full. Unless the queue isn't being processed.

Comment: @Kayaman BlockingQueue interface extends Collection and it offers `size()`?

Comment: @AmitBera yeah, noticed that. Although it was more important to know the internal implementation (so that it doesn't for example traverse the whole queue....although that would be a poor implementation).

Comment: @Kayaman, well, yes. I meant we need to override all content-modifying methods of a `BlockingQueue` interface, so we will know how much tasks were added by the user and how much were received by the executor itself. Probably, I was unclear, will try to express my thoughts in a more straight way.

Comment: @Xobotun why? If you look at my answer, you see that there's nothing hard about getting the current size of the queue, and it's not even inefficient.

Comment: @Kayaman, about getting the size of a queue – yeah, it's pretty much simple. :) I was talking more about the monitoring side of the issue. Well, everything will depend on how OP will implement it, that will be a story for another question. :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know from where you have got `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` class type of executor. But in java you can typecast  to `ThreadPoolExecutor` and get queue and it's size as below:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executorService =  (ThreadPoolExecutor )Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        executorService.getQueue().size()
```

Comment: okay. Try out the same method getQueue() on this class then, must work ideally.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in real-time as you're asking for is not so easy. You'll need to decorate the methods of `BlockingQueue` so that you can add code to execute immediately when the content of the queue changes.

You can then provide your queue to Spring's `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` like this:

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor() {
  @Override
  protected BlockingQueue<Runnable> createQueue(int queueCapacity) {

    // create and return your instance of blocking queue here
  }
};
```